# Custom Login Form Error : Redirecting to https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true using CredentialsProvider

Tags: next.js, next-auth

**DESCRIPTION:**
I'm facing while implementing custom login form in my nextjs site using next-auth.
It keeps on redirecting to "https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true"

SERVER SIDE CODE WRITTEN IN "[...nextauth.js]" FILE INSIDE "pages/api/auth/" folder.

```
    import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
    import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
    
    const providers = [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'credentials',
            name: 'credentials',
            authorize: async (credentials) => {
                console.log("AUTHORIZING...",credentials,req);
                const res = await fetch(process.env.apiURL+"api/users/authenticate", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                });
                const user = await res.json();
                if (res.ok && user) {
                    return user;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }),
    ];
    
    const callbacks = {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
            console.log("IN CALLBACK HERE!!!");
            const isAllowedToSignIn = true
            if (isAllowedToSignIn) {
              return true
            } else {
              return false
            }
        },
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            return baseUrl;
        },
        async session(session, token) {
          console.log("IN THE CALLBACK SESSION NOW");
          session.accessToken = token.accessToken
          return session
        }
    }
    
    const options = {
        providers,
        callbacks,
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        pages: {
            signIn: '/my-account',
            signUp: '/signup',
            error: '/my-account'
        },
        debug: true
    }

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
```

**MY CUSTOM LOGIN FORM'S SUBMIT BUTTON ACTION:**

```
const res = await signIn('credentials', { redirect: false, username: user.username, passw: user.passw, callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}` });
            console.log(res);
            if (res?.error) {
                console.error(res.error);
            }
            if (res.url) router.push(res.url);
```

**ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://localhost:3000/api/auth
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=PETSFINEST
```

ERROR IS
the Authorize function of Credentials Provider is not at all being called.. as soon as I press SIGNIN button from my custom login form, it simply redirects to "https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true" URL and thats it.

Please help guys.. what am I doing wrong here? There's no other details available anywhere, and I've followed the documentation provided on next-auth site.

Answer (score 14):

In my `.env`, Vercel added `VERCEL="1"` which caused this error for me.

Commenting out this var should fix this issue.

Comment: Just had this same issue, thanks. It seems like you can't even change it to a different value to stop this behaviour, which is annoying because I'd like to be able to just run `vercel env pull` without having to touch it.

Comment: I'd give you 10 upvotes if I could, it was so hard to find this answer. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my issue, but why? Agreed with Ben's point, this extra step is not ideal. Is this a bug report for Vercel? This wasnt causing an issue for me just a week ago.

Comment: This was the trick!

Comment: Someone give this man a raise. Spent hours trying to fix this.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and was not able to find solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Hey try changing to `http` on the `NEXTAUTH_URL` env variable
So change this:

```
    NEXTAUTH_URL=https://localhost:3000/api/auth
```

into

```
    NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth
```

Comment: It's a good catch.. but no difference in the error .. check out this screenshot: https://freeimage.host/i/VXVyrb

Comment: I was searching around for the opposite (testing HTTPS in localhost) and your answer helped me :) - thank you

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue. After banging my head against the wall for ages, it ends up https was being used because I was running it with Vercel...

So rather than using `vercel dev` I switched it to `npx next dev` and it resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me as well. I was not using vercel dev, but was using npm run dev, which was weirdly using "next dev" anyways... running it directly via npx next dev worked.

Answer (score 1):

use `NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000`

instead of `NEXTAUTH_URL=https://localhost:3000/api/auth`

Answer (score 0):

Open the browser inspect tools and check the network tab. Pay attention to the payload on the submit. You should have csrfToken showing a value. Check that email, password and csrf are present in the payload. This helped me solve my issue similar to this when implementing passwordless email form. Here is my custom signin...

```
import React from 'react'
import {getProviders, signIn} from 'next-auth/react'
import { getCsrfToken } from "next-auth/react"
import styles from '../../styles/signin.module.css'
import Logo from '../../components/Logo'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { GoogleLogin } from '../../components/GoogleLogin'

export default function SignIn ({ csrfToken, providers }) {
  console.log(providers.google.signinUrl);
  return (
    <div className={styles.content}>
      <div className={styles.cardWrapper}>
        <Logo className={styles.logo}/>
        <div className={styles.cardContent}>
          <form method="post" action="/api/auth/signin/email">
            <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" defaultValue={csrfToken} />
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder='Email..' />
            <button className={styles.primaryBtn} type="submit">Sign in with Email</button>
          </form>
          <p className={styles.seperator}> Or  </p>
          <form method="post" action="/api/auth/signin/google">
            <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" defaultValue={csrfToken} />
            <button className={styles.primaryBtn} type="submit">Sign in with Google</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken(context)
  const providers = await getProviders(context)
  return {
    props: { csrfToken, providers },
  }
}
```

I think you can do something similar for credentials as long as you have set it up correctly as per docs in [...nextauth].js.

The code above can be put into seperate components to "Reactify" the code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the issue an hour ago. My HTTP localhost was getting redirected to HTTPS when signing in. It would send the email but throw the error `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`.

None of the solutions above worked for me but removing `AUTH_TRUST_HOST=true` on `.env.local` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had both a `.env` file and a `.env.local` which had different things, deleting `.env.local` solved it

Answer (score -1):

I've been having the same exact issue and banging my head against the wall for a few hours trying to debug this. The problem for me was that my SMTP server string was still using the 'smtp.example.com' from the docs instead of (in my case) 'smtp.sendgrid.net'.

```bash
EMAIL_SERVER="smtp://<user>:<password>@smtp.example.com:587"
```

Answer (score -1):

Only if you are using docker,

Maybe I am the only one facing this issue, but after spending hours on this issue, turns out that `docker-compose.yml`

from `NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000"` to `NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000`

The quotes `"`